# Formatting Strings in TextField JavaFX

Tags: string, javafx, textfield

In my JavaFX application I am trying to format a String and then push it to TextField.

This is my code:

```
String result = "No of Rows Returned : " + repairHeaderEntities.size();

            if(null!=repairHeaderEntities && repairHeaderEntities.size()>0){
                result = result + "\n" + "\nRepair Status Code: "+entity.getRepairStatusCode();

analyzeResult.setText(result);
```

analyzeResult is the TextField fx id.

But in the output I am getting the following:

No of Rows Returned : 1Repair Status Code: ENDE

As you can see there output is not moving to a new line and is coming up in the same line.

Comment: Aside: there is no point in checking `null!=repairHeaderEntities`, since the previous line would already have thrown an exception if `repairHeaderEntities` were null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation for `TextField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextField.html):

> Text input component that allows a user to enter a **single line** of unformatted text. Unlike in previous releases of JavaFX, support for multi-line input is not available as part of the `TextField` control, however this is the sole-purpose of the `TextArea` control.

Use a `TextArea` in place of the `TextField`.

If you do not want the user to be able to edit the text in the text control, you could also consider using a `Label` instead.

Comment: Yessssss...Thanksss a lot .